# What are some nice fitness event/activity tracking devices?

Tags: wearable-technology

Are there any nice and affordable, wearable fitness-tracking devices, which can track calories consumed, burnt and also help manage time allotments to various activities like sleep, eating, etc?

---

Edited after [Mark](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/241/mark)'s [comment](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/387/what-are-some-nice-fitness-event-activity-tracking-devices#comment-764) below:

**Cost:** Would be nice if it's within $250

**Weight:** As it's a wearable, the lighter the better.

**Battery Life:** A decent battery life is okay, as I would be wearing it in my home most of the time, so I can charge it whenever it gets down.

**Software Compatibility:** If it comes with an app which can show my progress, etc. on my android phone, there's nothing like it.

As I'd be using it during exercise, something which is durable would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

Whilst most people I know have the ubiquitous  *Fitbit*, I have heard good things about the *Microsoft Band*. It is meant to have a few more features, although it is, unfortunately, lacking the Leaderboard community aspect. It is however compatible with Android, as is the Fitbit.

If money is no object, then why not go for an Apple Watch, whose features seem superlative? Although, I personally would wait for the Apple Watch 2, as the first version of anything generally has bugs that will be ironed out in the subsequent version. However, having said that it will not be compatible with your Android phone. Although, if money *really* is no object, you could always get an Apple phone as well.

You might want to take a look at [Best Fitness Trackers 2015](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/best-fitness-trackers,review-2066.html), from TomsGuide. They have come up with eight "top picks":

- Fitbit Charge HR;
- Jawbone Up Move;
- Garmin Vivoactive;
- Withings Activité Pop;
- Garmin Forerunner 225;
- Garmin Forerunner 15;
- Microsoft band, and finally;
- Moov.

Comment: This answer seems to be throwing many products at OP. Can you narrow it down a bit and compare the products? I also don't expect OP to ditch his Android phone just to track calories.

Comment: I believe Greenonline's response is on topic as OP did not specifically ask for a shortlist. It also adds values to other people who have similar questions. For example, it stopped me from asking another question as it was comprehensive.

Comment: @Cfinley - The comment about the additional purchase of an iPhone was a bit tongue-in-cheek, as the OP said that there was _no issue_ w.r.t. cost. :-)

Comment: @SS I never said that it should be deleted. I was only suggesting for Greenonline to clarify his post a bit. I _personally_ would prefer a product or two per answer on _my_ questions, as I can get a quick overview about the product. This lists a handful of products telling the OP to look into these devices without actually saying why they should look into them.

Comment: @Greenonline Ok. I'm the OP here, and I don't think **no issue wrt cost** meant that I can buy an iphone just for using the device. It is just a term used for signifying a considerable wide price range.

Comment: @Cfinley yes I get what you were saying. I was only suggesting that the bigger list is/could be useful for the wider community. I agree a few points of pros and cons of each or some of the options would definitely add value.

Comment: @Dawny33 - I fully understand that, and like I said, that comment was a throw away light-hearted attempt at humour (which obviously failed). W.R.T clarification of my answer, I can certainly do that, as the bare list is, admittedly, somewhat lacking in content - however, in the past when I have provided the beef of the link (in case of link death) I have been accused of plagiarising the link's content, and was told, instead, to give a brief summary/synopsis of the link's (review's) content. That is what I tried to achieve with my answer, although maybe I went overboard on the brevity.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't mind paying near to $250 on a fitness watch, you need to check out the Garmin Vívoactive 3. This is the best ever I could suggest within your budget and also it has all the features you want like you said above. BUT, if you need to make a second choice, you should consider the Fitbit Ionic.

It is like a straight fight between Pepsi vs Cola, DC vs Marvel, PS4 vs Xbox One, Android vs iOS. So the rival for Garmin is Fitbit. You can take a look at the [comparison](https://wearvs.com/compare/fitbit-ionic-vs-garmin-vivoactive-3) or read review before making final choice.

*Some additional info*.

**Weight** :

Fitbit Ionic = 50 grams (or to be exact = 49.8952 grams)

Garmin Vivoactive 3 = 43 grams

So the winner here is Fitbit Ionic

**Battery life**  :

Fitbit = 4 days
Garmin = 7 days

So the winner here is Garmin Vívoactive 3

**Software Compatibility and Features** :

Garmin - If you are really into fitness freak or maybe something like endurance athletes and detailed performance junkie. This is the best to utilize a lot of activities such as cycling, golf, skiing, sports tracking, etc.

Fitbit - It is preferable for people who desire a less complicated user interface, are keen on daily activity monitoring and get social functions.

**Conclusion** :

What you stated above "track calories consumed, burnt and also help manage time allotments to various activities like sleep, eating, etc.."

It is all can be done via both fitness tracker, but in term more added function or more details tracking, the winner is Garmin is here. But if you are not really into that, the best is Fitbit Ionic, with great display quality (that is the thing that make the battery duration for the Ionic less than Vivoactive) and less complicated user interface, it could be great for you which is at home the most of the time.

Finally, my guess, the Fitbit Ionic is more suitable for you. For more details specs, i guess you should check out their official website, it might be a very long answer if i need to elaborate all of the details aspects and features.

Comment: Welcome to Hardware recs! Can you add a few more details about the products to your answer please. The OP is interested in the weight, battery life, and software compatibility, which I not see mentioned in your answer. Can you please [edit] your answer to include this information?

Comment: Adding relevant information from the comparison would be good too; we try to refrain from link-centric answers, as they hurt legibility and are susceptible to link rot.

Comment: Hello everyone, i added a few more details about the products